# Connected nodes with the most in common

Tags: neo4j, cypher

i have a site I'm working on that matches people based on common interests or skills. I can connect them easily enough via Cyper to find others but what I would like to do is order then by the number of common connection they have. If person A's has 10 common interests with person B, I want they ordered above person C that only shares 4 common interests with person A. Bonus points if I can also count the number of common interests. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try counting the number of relationships in the pattern for an intersecting interest. Something like this:

```
MATCH (a:Person)-[r:INTERESTED_IN]->(:Thing)<-[:INTERESTED_IN]-(b:Person)
    WHERE NOT a=b
WITH a, b, count(r) AS commonInterestCount
RETURN a.name, b.name, commonInterestCount ORDER BY commonInterestCount DESC
```

Comment: Since there is no difference between `a` and `b` in your pattern, each node matched as `a` will also be matched as `b`. That's not wrong, but sometimes undesirable. If so, add something to make the match about a particular node–`(a:Person {pid:1})`–or do `WHERE ID(a) > ID(b)` to break the symmetry.